# How to remove whitespace on a nav bar

Tags: html, css

Here's a screenshot of the issue I'm having:

[image: Header]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove the empty space on either side of the navbar. I've tried making the margin and padding 0 but it hasn't been working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the html:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

header {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#header img {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #009BB2;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: maroon;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

img.size {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

figure {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="The Seasons" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Fall</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Spring</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Summer</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Winter</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h1>The Four Seasons of the Earth</h1>
    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/fall_front.png" alt="Fall" />
    </figure>
    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/winter_front.png" alt="Winter" />
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/spring_front.png" alt="Spring" />
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/summer_front.png" alt="Summer" />
    </figure>


  </section>



</div>
```

Comment: you want to remove the empty green color of either side?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem? The nav stretches to the far ends of `#wrap` for me. does your code accurately reproduce the layout problem? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWGOpR

Comment: I believe Jeff Miller has the correct answer, but you might want to clarify if you want to shorten the width of your nav background or if you want the nav to be 100% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `nav ul` selector and that will remove the whitespace from the sides.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

header {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#header img {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #009BB2;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: maroon;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

img.size {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

figure {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="The Seasons" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Fall</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Spring</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Summer</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Winter</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h1>The Four Seasons of the Earth</h1>
    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/fall_front.png" alt="Fall" />
    </figure>
    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/winter_front.png" alt="Winter" />
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/spring_front.png" alt="Spring" />
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
      <img class="size" src="images/summer_front.png" alt="Summer" />
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're maxing out the width at 1000px:

```
#wrap{
    width:1000px;
}
```

The nav is within that, so it can't stretch wider than that.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted by others, you're setting the width to 1000px;

Change`#wrap{width: 1000px}` to `#wrap{width: 100%}`